# Why is my query in CodeIgniter function not returning anything?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a MySQL table named **tbl_br_office_sic**. The table has 4 fields, **officeid**, **servicetypeid**, **name**,and **naics_id**.

I only want all the naics_id's of a certain officeid.

So in my model, I have a function that queries and returns the data to be used in the controller.

The function is defined as follow:

```
 function getNaics($officeid){
      $this->db->select('naics_id');
      $this->db->from("tbl_br_office_sic");
      $this->db->where('officeid', $officeid);
      $data = $this->db->get();
      return $data;
   }
```

The query the function generates should be like:

```
 select naics_id from tbl_br_office_sic where officeid = $officeid;
```

The $officeid variable has a valid value. However, the $data variable returned is an empty array. 
What did I possibly do wrong in the syntax or anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not **getting** any results, you need to use `->result()`. The correct approach for your example is:

```
 function getNaics($officeid){
      $this->db->select('naics_id');
      $this->db->from("tbl_br_office_sic");
      $this->db->where('officeid', $officeid);
      $query= $this->db->get();
      $data = ($query->num_rows())? $query->result():false;
      return $data;
   }
```

this executes the query and returns the results (or false, in case no records found)

more info on [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#)

Comment: If I didn't return the result, what value is in $data then?

Comment: $data would be false if there are no results

Comment: it is still not returning anything. What can be possibly wrong?

Comment: remove the where clause and see what is happening, maybe $officeid doesn't exist in table or has no value? you can also print_r($data);die; to see what it spits out

Comment: Then it returns something

Comment: The return of `get()` is an instance of `CI_DB_result` so that's what `$data` is - if the query succeeds. The value could be false if the query fails. A failure in this context means the DB choked on the query, the DB connection dropped, or some similar problem, But, _a query that does not return any rows_ **is not a failure**. In other words, the returned `CI_DB_result` might have any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use to get result result() or result_array()

function getNaics($officeid){
      $this->db->select('naics_id');
      $this->db->from("tbl_br_office_sic");
      $this->db->where('officeid', $officeid);
      $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
      return $data;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getNaics($officeid= false){
        if($officeid=== false)
        {
            $this->db->order_by('name','ASC');
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_br_office_sic');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $this->db->order_by('name','ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_br_office_sic', array('officeid' => $officeid));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

You can try this, thanks